# NSIS MessageBox jump offset

Tags: nsis

I'm not able to understand what's wrong with the below code for jumping to particular offset if MessageBox returns IDNO.

Below code is to quit installer while IDNO is selected, but it always jumping to `Goto endCurrentBlock` line

```
    MessageBox MB_YESNO|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Would you like to continue installation?" IDNO +3
    !insertmacro ShowStatus "Failed to install software"
    Goto endCurrentBlock
    Quit
```

If I use a absoule label for jump it's working good. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jumping by offset skips x number of NSIS instructions but `!insertmacro` is a preprocessor instruction that might expand to zero, one or several NSIS instructions.

It is not recommended to combine offset jumps and `!insertmacro` because it can break your code just by changing the macro...

Comment: Right. I missed this. Defenitely +3 offset indicating line inside the macro which consists 4 lines in it. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: You may have a simpler time with labels or LogicLib. This way you don't have to change all the offsets when a macro changes.